# updates of the document vectors in doc2vec (PV-DM) in gensim

Tags: python, numpy, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I'm trying to understand the PV-DM implementation with averaging in gensim.
In the function `train_document_dm` in `doc2vec.py` the return value ("errors") of `train_cbow_pair` is in the case of averaging (`cbow_mean=1`) not divided by the number of input vectors (`count`).
According to this explanation there should be a division by the number of documents in the case of averaging the input vectors: [word2vec Parameter Learning Explained, equation (23)](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~ronxin/pdf/w2vexp.pdf).
Here is the code from `train_document_dm`:

```py
l1 = np_sum(word_vectors[word2_indexes], axis=0)+np_sum(doctag_vectors[doctag_indexes], axis=0)  
count = len(word2_indexes) + len(doctag_indexes)  
if model.cbow_mean and count > 1:  
    l1 /= count  
neu1e = train_cbow_pair(model, word, word2_indexes, l1, alpha,
                                learn_vectors=False,  learn_hidden=learn_hidden)  
if not model.cbow_mean and count > 1:  
    neu1e /= count  
if learn_doctags:  
    for i in doctag_indexes:  
        doctag_vectors[i] += neu1e * doctag_locks[i]  
if learn_words:  
    for i in word2_indexes:  
        word_vectors[i] += neu1e * word_locks[i]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say V is defined as the average of `A`, `B`, and `C`:

V = (A + B + C) / 3

Let's set `A = 5`, `B = 6`, and `C = 10`. And let's say we want `V` equal 10.

We run the calculation (forward propagation), and the value of `V`, the average of the three numbers, is 7. Thus the correction needed for V is +3.

To apply this correction to A, B, and C, do we also *divide* that correction by 3, to get +1 against each? In that case `A = 6`, `B = 7`, and `C = 11` – and now `V` is just 8. It'd still need another +2 to match the target.

So, no. The proper correction to all of the components of `V`, in the case where `V` is an average, is the same as the correction to `V` – in this case, +3. If we were apply that, we'd reach our proper target value of 10:

```
A = 8, B = 9, C = 13
V = (8 + 9 + 13) / 3 = 10
```

The same thing is happening the gensim backpropagation. In the case of averaging, the full corrective value (times the learning-rate `alpha`) is applied to each of the constituent vectors.

(If using a sum-of-vectors to create V instead, *then* the error would need to be divided by the count of constituent vectors - to split the error over them all, and not apply it redundantly.)